# d3.js bar chart: .text doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I'm building a simple bar chart using d3.js and it works fine. 
However, when I try to display texts on each bar, nothing happens. The console doesn't return any error so I can't understand the problem.
My code is available [here](http://bl.ocks.org/cflavs/bddd46ee4c5e4d888c0d5785e6dba255), I tried to display simple text like "Hello" but still nothing shows up.

Comment: Where do you want the text to appear, and what value do you want it to have for a given bar?

Comment: I want to appear in the end of each bar the value of  the vacant (atribute of freqData variable).

Comment: Have you tried working through this tutorial: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart?  I realise that the tutorial has a vertical rather than horizontal chart, but I hope it's still useful.  You're trying to apply the text labels via a selectAll on the `rect`s, and not a selectAll on the `text`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Appending texts to a `rect` element in SVG.

**Solution:**

Append the texts to the SVG or to a group.

**Instructions:**

You are appending your texts to the rectangles. Nothing will show up as an error in the console because there is no error to show, but the texts won't appear.

You have to create a variable for the texts:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll(".mytexts")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append("text");
```

And then setting the attributes:

```
texts.attr("class", "value")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return widthScale(d.vacant); })
              .attr("y", heightScale.rangeBand() / 2)
              .attr("dx", -3)
              .attr("dy", ".35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .text(function(d) { return format(d.vacant); });
```

Don't forget to change the CSS accordingly.

Comment: Very nice explanation!!!! Thanks a million!
Everything is working now, I really wasn't understanding how to link the texts to rects variable and svg.

Comment: No worries! For linking the texts to the rectangles the best approach is creating groups (<g> elements in svg).